# HackerEarth Runtime Error - NZEC in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
N = int(input())

list = []

while(N>0):

    n = int(input())
    list.append(n)
    N = N-1

Q = int(input())

while(Q>0):

    check = int(input())
    count = list.count(check)
    if(count==0):
        print("NOT PRESENT")
    else:
        print(count)
    Q = Q-1
```

The above is the code I wrote in hackerearth. I get response as a runtime error. But when I try in my ubuntu python console it works perfect

Comment: i do not know anything about HackerEarth... but if their interpreter is python 2 (and not python3) you might try to replace `input()` with `raw_input()`.

Comment: What was the error ?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information provided, it looks like you're trying to solve [this problem](https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/data-structures/arrays/1-d/practice-problems/algorithm/memorise-me/).

The input array is a list of elements all provided in a single line. Your code uses 'input()', which reads an entire line at a time. However, it would not be able to type-cast to integer because there is space characters.

Culprit code :-

```
N = int(input())
list = []
while(N>0):
    n = int(input())
    list.append(n)
    N = N-1
```

Change this to :-

```
n = int(input())
arr = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
```

Also, I would advice against using the variable `list` as it over-rides the global meaning of that variable/type.

Since you said that it worked on your local machine, I think you're manually entering the inputs. The correct way to test if it works locally would be to write the sample input to a file, say `input.sample`. Then run the following command(s) on the command line (I am assuming you're using a *nix system and that the python code is in the file `code.py`)

```
$> python3 code.py < input.sample
```

This should have given you the error :-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/test2.py", line 7, in <module>
      n = int(input())
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1 1 1 2 2 0'
```